# Vagrant Issue: The box 'lucid64' could not be found

Tags: django, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. I'm trying to setup vagrant and virtualbox for my django projects. I modified the vagrantfile as instructed on

I get the following error:[on this website](http://blog.smalleycreative.com/tutorials/setup-a-django-vm-with-vagrant-virtualbox-and-chef/)

> There was a problem with the configuration of Vagrant. The error message(s)
>   are printed below:
>
> vm:
>   * The box 'lucid64' could not be found.

i'm using a MAC OS, 
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Try downloading the lucid64.box file manually and adding it to the available VM list with ``vagrant box add lucid64 /path/to/box/file``.  You can verify it's availability with ``vagrant box list ``.

Comment: Please update your question with an answer.

Answer (score 3):

A "vagrant box add lucid64 http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid64.box" did the trick! thanks.

Comment: Worked for me with Vagrant 2.  You should mark it as answered.